# How to URI Encode pipe character in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, url, uri

Is there an add-on or an *about:config* setting to force Firefox encode it's URL?

#### Example

In Firefox, typing the following and hitting go/enter `http://www.example.com/go|here/again`, I would expect it to encode any special characters, such that it would resolve to `http://www.example.com/go%7chere/again`.

I believe it works correctly in other browsers (IE/chrome), but am struggling for a universal solution in Firefox.

Comment: IE and Chrome are broken as they do not follow RFC 3986 [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). The `|` symbol is not an allowed character in a URI.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think it's not that IE/Chrome use that symbol, but that they automatically URI Encode it, because it is not allowed.  They may be behaving correctly.  What I would prefer is to visually see it, but behind the scenes, the user agent automatically to encode illegal characters.  Firefox will send it, even though it's illegal.